# Python - Would you like to go again feature not working

Tags: python-3.x

My Python Program isn't working, it's due in a few days and I need to get it working. The problem is the would you like to go again part. Here it is:

```
n1 = input ("How many bottles would you like?\n")
n = int (n1)
playing = True

while playing:
    while n > 1:
        print (n," green bottles sitting on a wall,")
        print (" ")
        print (n," green bottles sitting on a wall,")
        print (" ")
        print ("And if one green bottle should accidently fall,")
        print (" ")

        print ("There would be ", n-1," green bottles sitting on a wall")
        print (" ")
        n = n - 1
    print ("1 green bottle, sitting on a wall,")
    print (" ")
    print ("1 green bottle, sitting on a wall,")
    print (" ")
    print ("And if one green bottle should accidently fall,")
    print (" ")
    print ("There would be no green bottles sitting on a wall")

    again = input ("Would you like to go again?")
    if again == "yes" or "Yes":
        n1 = input ("How many bottles would you like then?")
        n = int (n1)
    if again == "no" or "No":
        playing = False
```

The problem is that when it asks me whether I'd like to go again, it will say "How many bottles would you like then?" even if I put "no" in as an answer to it. I'd like to find out how to fix it so the program will stop when I enter "no" and I would also like to know how it's done.

Comment: Do you want us to contact your teacher to give you more time? Please clarify what kind of help you are looking for and provide [MCVE]  (your current sample definitely is not "minimal").

Comment: Also provide a detailed example of what's going wrong, what errors you might see, and what you'd expect. Looking at your code I would presume it's always asking you how many bottles you want for your next turn. As a matter of fact, before coming here for help, it's actually faster to look at some python examples, and read the docs about expressions and conditions and operators such as `==` and `or` plus the docs about type `str()`. That's little text to read and provides you with more understanding than just asking someone to write code for you. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also no you don't need to contact my school lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
if again == "yes" or "Yes":
```

This should be changed into

```
if again == "yes" or again == "Yes":
```

What happens? Python evaluates first `again == "yes"` and subsequently solely the term `"Yes"`. The latter will be always `true`, cause its value is not `0` (and, hence, automatically `true` for Python)

The same holds for

```
if again == "no" or "No":
```

which consistently will be evaluated as `true`.